# Why changing page footer content draws a line to the top of the page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I wanted to change my footer content so it would be a text I chose instead of the page number. But making this change draws a line to the top of the page. How to get rid of it?

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}  % The style class
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    % headers and footers

\pagestyle{fancy}        % set the pagestyle to fancy to include headers and footers
\fancyhf{}               % clear the header and footer
\fancyfoot[C]{This document is written in \LaTeX. $\odot$ Last update \today}

\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image: image of the pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

to the preamble of your document.